# How to visualize touches with android (Nexus One)

Tags: android, visualization

Do you know if there is a tool/setting that allows me to visualize the touch events while using my phone? I would like to use it for a usabilty test.

There is a tool for the iPhone that does exactly what I need (It´s called DisplayRecorder)
In this video you can see what I mean: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WGOrkDxgMME

I didn´t find a similar tool for android. I´m not sure if it works with the dev tools setting "Pointer Location" - my Nexus One crashes when I try to set it.
Does anybody know if this works while using the phone as normal? In terms of a layer on top of the normal application?

Hope someone can help me! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I used a [small "joke" application creating electrical sparks where one touched](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.diotasoft.spark). That's probably not really what you want, but maybe you could craft your own app using the same principle: a transparent overlay, registering touches and displaying a haircross where they are detected (and possibly showing coordinates in a textbox or something).

Comment: Thanks for that one :-)
It is good to know that it is technically possible to code a transparten overlay!
Does it register multiple fingers or only one at a time?

@Own app: I thought of that too. But there is very few time left in my project, so I wondered if there is already a solution. But I only found "multitouch testing apps" till now.

Comment: Apparently just a finger at a time, but I suppose it could do more. That said, I think the transparency part is easy; but I'm not sure it's as easy to transfer the events to the underlying app. Sorry I'm too lazy to attempt it myself (unless you can wait, like, 10 years)

Comment: Ok thanks for that hint! Well, then I have to go on with my research.
Perhaps I´ll have the time to code this in a new project :-/